# Can't get v-model work with Composition API and Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-composition-api

I've read several posts on stackoverflow and other websites, but still can't figure out what's going wrong in my case.

I'm building an app following composition api approach and using a variable called *modelStartDate* (which I initiate at Jan 3, 2022). This is how my store looks:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    modelStartDate: new Date(2022, 0, 3)
  },
  mutations: {
    modelStartDateMutation(state, newDate) {
      state.modelStartDate = newDate
    }
  },
  actions: {
  },
  getters: {
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

In the relevant Vue file, I have the following code snippet:

```
<template>
      <nav class="left-bar">
      <div class="block" id="modelStartDate">
        <label>Model start date</label>
        <input type="date" v-model="modelStartDateProxy" />
      </div>

      <p>{{ modelStartDate }}</p>
      
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import { computed } from '@vue/runtime-core'
export default {
    setup() {
        
        const store = useStore()
        const modelStartDateProxy  = computed({
            get: () => store.state.modelStartDate,
            set: (newDate) => store.commit("modelStartDateMutation", newDate)
        })
        const modelStartDate = store.state.modelStartDate

        return { modelStartDateProxy, modelStartDate }
    }


}
</script>
```

When I run the page, the paragraph tag prints the right date, however the input tag, where the user can change the date, is empty (I was expecting Jan 3, 2022 to be pre-selected). When the date is changed, nothing seems to change in the app. I'm getting no errors. Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

Also, can I access store's modelStartDate state without having to define it separately (redundantly?) in the vue setup() section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't know which tutorial you read. But to me, the problem is here:

```js
const modelStartDateProxy = computed({
    get: () => store.state.modelStartDate,
    set: (newDate) => store.commit("modelStartDateMutation", newDate)
})

const modelStartDate = store.state.modelStartDate
```

1. The snippet

```
const modelStartDateProxy = computed({
    get: () => store.state.modelStartDate,
    set: (newDate) => store.commit("modelStartDateMutation", newDate)
})
```

is weird to me.

2. Duplicate of `store.state.modelStartDate`. DRY.
3. `<p>{{ modelStartDate }}</p>` render data from `const modelStartDate = store.state.modelStartDate`. But the data was only assign once. So the new value was not render on input was changed.
   Solution:

```
const modelStartDate = computed(() => store.state.modelStartDate);
```

You can take a look at this [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-knuth-i1i3ur?file=/src/App.vue).

Answer (score 0):

The html element input returns a string: "YYYY-MM-DD". Therefore you need the syntax `new Date(value)`

Take a look at [this playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<template>
  <label>Model start date</label>
  <input type="date" v-model="modelStartDateProxy" />
  <p>{{ modelStartDateProxy }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import { store } from './store.js' //mock-up store
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
export default {
  setup() {
    const modelStartDateProxy = computed({
      get: () => store.state.modelStartDate,
      set: (newDate) => store.commit(newDate) // Use real Vuex syntax
    })
    return { modelStartDateProxy }
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
//Mock-up Store (not real vuex)
import {reactive} from 'vue'
export const store = reactive({
  state: {
    modelStartDate: new Date(2022, 0, 3)
  },
  commit: (value) => store.state.modelStartDate = new Date(value) // new Date(value)
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, very helpful. Interestingly this approach does not update the html element when a (different) date is selected. When I try the same approach with an input element, but type number instead of type date, everything works like a charm. Any idea what might be causing this?